# Is it a best practice to locally delete a branch after get it merged?

Tags: git

I just saw one of my teammates doing it and was wondering the possible reasons. Is it a best practice? If so, why is that?

Also, wouldn't it make branch name conflicts more likely to happen on upstream?

Comment: There are no any recommendations in this area; every team decide for themselves. For me the reason to delete unused branches is to avoid long output of `git branch` and shorter prefixes in branch name completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **YES** its a best practice now why is it is a question.

Basically, if the purpose of the branch was to fix a bug and it has served it then there is no point in keeping it. Deleting the branch will help you to keep your local clean. Now if the purpose of a branch is its say adding new feature than maybe you want to keep it to fix any bug found later regarding the same feature(Ideally you should still create new branch). But again once the goal is achieved what is the point in keeping it?

Simply, there is no compulsion in deleting the branch but not deleting will make things difficult and complex, That's all.

Also, check this [blog](https://ardalis.com/why-delete-old-git-branches/) if you want to know more.

Answer (score 2):

It's up to the individual developer whether they want to delete their branches locally.  There are some reasons that one might want to do so:

- Tab completion, UI branch lists, and other editor and shell functionality will work better if you have only active branches.
- Keeping only unmerged branches makes it easy to see what work you have in progress.

If you prefer to keep older branches to have a historical record of your work, or are just lazy and don't want to think about deleting them, that's also fine.

It *is*, however, a best practice to delete them from shared repositories.  That's because fetches and pushes by default look up the entire list of references.  If there are many, many references, the amount of time and bandwidth to transfer them can be significant, and Git will also try to consider all those references when determining what to download to try to send the smallest amount of data.  It is often faster to send a small amount of duplicated data than to get the smallest pack file for transfer.

In addition, all of the UI benefits mentioned above are relevant for large shared repositories where you may want to find a branch or tag quickly.  Even if you don't use those features, your collaborators who do will appreciate your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would delete branches on the *remote* when they are merged, as keeping them around is unnecessary and just adds noise and clutter. It's up to you to decide if you also want to delete local branches that you had checked out at one time, that no longer are on the server. In general I prefer deleting them as it's unnecessary to keep them around if I don't have my own new commits on them.

Regarding your additional question:

> Wouldn't it make branch name conflicts more likely to happen?

Not really; once a branch is deleted on the remote it's perfectly reasonable to re-use a branch name again. Especially for one-time throwaway branches used in Git Flow, such as "merge-release-into-develop", for example. That branch may be created, merged, and deleted over and over again.

As a side note, here's some anecdotal evidence of why it's a good idea to keep up with it and delete unneeded local branches. I recently got a new work laptop and cloned the repo. I've been keeping up with it and currently have only 3 local branches. Not long after that I realized I had some code committed on my old laptop that I hadn't pushed yet. So I copied the repo from my old laptop to my new one. In that repo, I had 112 local branches! I'd estimate at least 75% of those branches have already been merged and can safely be deleted, and another 15% are never going to be merged and can also be deleted, but I was reluctant to purge any until I had the time to figure out which ones I could delete. In retrospect I wish I would have kept up with it. I'll probably be carrying that copy of the repo around with me for a while.